# Get entity group count always return 0

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Following the [GAE official doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Java_Entity_group_metadata) i try to test it in  my local dev environment(unit test), unfortunately the entity group count always return 0:

```
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    MemcacheService memcacheService = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();

    Entity entity1 = new Entity("Simple");
    Key key1 = ds.put(entity1);
    Key entityGroupKey = Entities.createEntityGroupKey(key1);
    //should print 1, but 0
    showEntityGroupCount(ds, memcacheService, entityGroupKey);

    Entity entity2 = new Entity("Simple", key1);
    Key key2 = ds.put(entity2);
    //should print 2, but still 0
    showEntityGroupCount(ds, memcacheService, entityGroupKey);
```

below are copied from [the doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/metadataqueries#Java_Entity_group_metadata) for quick reference:

```
// A simple class for tracking consistent entity group counts
class EntityGroupCount implements Serializable {
  long version; // Version of the entity group whose count we are tracking
  int count;
  EntityGroupCount(long version, int count) {
    this.version = version;
    this.count = count;
  }
}

// Display count of entities in an entity group, with consistent caching
void showEntityGroupCount(DatastoreService ds, MemcacheService cache, PrintWriter writer,
                          Key entityGroupKey) {
  EntityGroupCount egCount = (EntityGroupCount) cache.get(entityGroupKey);
  if (egCount != null && egCount.version == getEntityGroupVersion(ds, null, entityGroupKey)) {
    // Cached value matched current entity group version, use that
    writer.println(egCount.count + " entities (cached)");
  } else {
    // Need to actually count entities. Using a transaction to get a consistent count
    // and entity group version.
    Transaction tx = ds.beginTransaction();
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(tx, new Query(entityGroupKey));
    int count = pq.countEntities(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5000));
    cache.put(entityGroupKey,
              new EntityGroupCount(getEntityGroupVersion(ds, tx, entityGroupKey), count));
    tx.rollback();
    writer.println(count + " entities");
  }
}
```

Any ideas about this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried it deployed? Often stuff does not work on the dev server but works when deployed.

Comment: I think you are right, i forget i was on dev server. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities.createEntityGroupKey() is being called twice as a result of method nesting.  Change both occurrences of

```
showEntityGroupCount(ds, memcacheService, entityGroupKey);
```

to

```
showEntityGroupCount(ds, memcacheService, key1);
```

and the correct counts appear (in the development environment anyway).

Comment: Good catch! you are right, can't believe the official doc is buggy and misleading, anyway i should spot that. Thanks so much.

Comment: I'm quite proud of finding this answer, it took some troubleshooting, and I had a growing determination to persist and not to allow this problem to defeat me :-)